# Add GET parameter to the url name - Django

Tags: django, django-urls

Currently I can pass a GET parameter from my html template like this.

```
<a href="display-associations/players/?association={{ association.user.username }}">View Players</a>
```

But can I do it through a url name parameter? I want something like following.

```
<a href="{% url 'player-registration' %}">Add Player</a>
```

I cannot figure out how to add GET parameter to the url-name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="{% url 'player-registration' %}?association={{ association.user.username }}">Add Player</a>
```

use like this

**Edit**:
`"` location fixed in `href`